# Recovery files attatched in SMF forum with crypto-names

Tags: php, mysql, smf, smf-forum

I have more than 2000 files that are in a old SMF forum ( 1.x Simple Machine Forum) with their filenames encrypted in the directory (crypto-name is like "file ID + hash", without extension).

Now I need to download all files with their real filenames and extensions. I would like to download all files through cpanel in one unique  operation, but when I do it, and I try to rename, the file crash and don´t open.

When I download one by one through SMF posts, the file arrives perfectly with their realname and extension, but is a very long operation to this number of files.

When I rename the file in the server by cpanel and after download, the file crashes too.

There is any way to download all files restored with realnames and extensions out of smf ? I need a unique operation. I tried to make a php script but this kind of code goes out of my knowledge.

What I know is the files have their real names in mysql.

For example:
In mysql a file is named like: "finances.doc" with ID: 113.
In attachments folder, the file is named "113_finances_docA1254484b6545c55645"

Thanks by suggestions.

Comment: When you say `download all files`, what do you mean? Do you mean locally to your computer? Do you mean through FTP? Do you mean offer a 1 click solution in the browser that will prompt to download all the files? please clarify.

Comment: Hi. I mean to download all by FTP.
I've downloaded all the files but found the problem all are corrupted and do not open in their associated programs (word, excel, pdf, etc.).
This is the reason for my need to rename all the files on the server to their original names and extensions (which are in mysql) and after that, I can download all the files by FTP.